# Why is my index out of range? IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, pycharm

I have been trying to make a web-scraper for rightmove for a while, and I am having trouble with an error message stating my list is out of range. There are no errors in the code, but it refuses to export the data to a CSV file when run.

Error Message:

```
HTTP GET request to URL: https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for- sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=REGION%5E93917&index=0&propertyTypes=&mustHave=&dontShow=&furnishTypes=&keywords= | Status code: 200
HTTP GET request to URL: https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=REGION%5E93917&index=24&propertyTypes=&mustHave=&dontShow=&furnishTypes=&keywords= | Status code: 200
HTTP GET request to URL: https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=REGION%5E93917&index=48&propertyTypes=&mustHave=&dontShow=&furnishTypes=&keywords= | Status code: 200
HTTP GET request to URL: https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=REGION%5E93917&index=72&propertyTypes=&mustHave=&dontShow=&furnishTypes=&keywords= | Status code: 200
HTTP GET request to URL: https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=REGION%5E93917&index=96&propertyTypes=&mustHave=&dontShow=&furnishTypes=&keywords= | Status code: 200
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.1.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.1.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/myrightmove/script.py", line 61, in <module>
    scraper.run()
  File "C:/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/myrightmove/script.py", line 56, in run
    self.to_csv()
  File "C:/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/myrightmove/script.py", line 40, in to_csv
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=self.results[0].keys())
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Working example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


class RightmoveScraper:
    results = []

    def fetch(self, url):
        print('HTTP GET request to URL: %s' % url, end='')
        response = requests.get(url)
        print(' | Status code: %s' % response.status_code)

        return response

    def parse(self, html):
        content = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

        titles = [title.text.strip() for title in content.findAll('h2', {'class': 'propertyCard.title'})]
        addresses = [address['content'] for address in content.findAll('meta', {'itemprop': 'streetAddr'})]
        descriptions = [description.text for description in content.findAll('span', {'data-test': 'property-description'})]
        prices = [price.text.strip() for price in content.findAll('div', {'class': 'propertyCard-priceValue'})]
        dates = [date.text.split(' ')[-1] for date in content.findAll('span', {'class': 'propertyCard-branchSummary-addedOrReduced'})]
        sellers = [seller.text.split('by')[-1].strip() for seller in content.findAll('span', {'class': 'propertyCard-branchSummary-branchName'})]
        images = [image['src'] for image in content.findAll('img', {'itemprop': 'image'})]

        for index in range(0, len(titles)):
            self.results.append({
                'title': titles[index],
                'address': addresses[index],
                'description': descriptions[index],
                'price': prices[index],
                'date': dates[index],
                'seller': sellers[index],
                'image': images[index],
            })

    def to_csv(self):
        with open('rightmove.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=self.results[0].keys())
            writer.writeheader()

            for row in self.results:
                writer.writerow(row)

            print('Stored results to "rightmove.csv"')

    def run(self):
        for page in range(0, 5):
            index = page * 24
            url = 'https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=REGION%5E93917&index=' + str(index) + '&propertyTypes=&mustHave=&dontShow=&furnishTypes=&keywords='

            response = self.fetch(url)
            self.parse(response.text)

        self.to_csv()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scraper = RightmoveScraper()
    scraper.run()
```

Any ideas on how to solve this type of problem?

Comment: You say that "There are no errors in the code" but that when you run the code you get  `IndexError: list index out of range`. Doesn't that mean that there is an error in your code? In any event, it seems that `self.results` is an empty list since passing it the index `0` triggers that error.

Comment: Ahhh how I have missed the pedanticness of stackoverflow.... Yes, errors appear in the python console, but before the code is run there appears to be no errors in the in-line code; only when the code is run, errors appear in the console, so yes, technically, there are obviously still errors in the code. On another note, thank you for spotting an error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trace back the error, printing out the values of `self.results` in the `parse()` function, it will become clear that for some reason, you are not appending anything to `self.results`.

I checked the `titles` field and it seems like you have a typo: **you are searching in the content for `propertyCard.title`, when you should probably be searching for `propertyCard-title`**.

Similarly, you should go through the rest of the fields that you are trying to add to `self.results` and attempt to find any errors in that part of your code (shown below).

(Hint: check the line `addresses = ...` and make sure you entered the correct value for `itemprop`.)

```
titles = [title.text.strip() for title in content.findAll('h2', {'class': 'propertyCard-title'})]
addresses = [address['content'] for address in content.findAll('meta', {'itemprop': 'streetAddr'})]
descriptions = [description.text for description in content.findAll('span', {'data-test': 'property-description'})]
prices = [price.text.strip() for price in content.findAll('div', {'class': 'propertyCard-priceValue'})]
dates = [date.text.split(' ')[-1] for date in content.findAll('span', {'class': 'propertyCard-branchSummary-addedOrReduced'})]
sellers = [seller.text.split('by')[-1].strip() for seller in content.findAll('span', {'class': 'propertyCard-branchSummary-branchName'})]
images = [image['src'] for image in content.findAll('img', {'itemprop': 'image'})]

for index in range(0, len(titles)):
    self.results.append({
        'title': titles[index],
        'address': addresses[index],
        'description': descriptions[index],
        'price': prices[index],
        'date': dates[index],
        'seller': sellers[index],
        'image': images[index],
    })
```